# Limited use of RAM with big raster layers in R

Tags: r, memory-management, raster, ram

I'm using a group of **big raster** layers to analyse some management aspects in UK. Each layer got the followings:

> class: RasterLayer
>   dimensions: 65240, 65628, 4281570720  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
>   resolution: 10, 10  (x, y)
>   extent: -80, 656200, 5300, 657700  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
>   coord.ref.: +proj=tmerc +lat_0=49 +lon_0=-2 +k=0.9996012717 +x_0=400000 +y_0=-100000 +datum=OSGB36 +units=m +no_defs +ellps=airy+towgs84=446.448,-125.157,542.060,0.1502,0.2470,0.8421,-20.4894 
>   data source: E:\Land Component Management\Land_Management_Control\R_Work\TempDir\r_tmp_2018-08-31_100516_1544_40026.grd
>   names: layer
>  
>   values: 0, 77  (min, max)

I have uploaded the data to my working directory using the following code:

```
raster_files = list.files(path = '.', pattern = '.tif$', full.names = TRUE)
```

Then I have retrieved each layer using the below code to get the each layer.

```
LayerType1 = raster(raster_files[1])
```

I'm using a windows server 2016 with system type 64bit and 64GB RAM.
As you can see, the layers are not in memory, but is been uploaded to a temporary directory. My problem is **my machine is only using less that 25% of the total RAM while processing these rasters**.

I've tested different options of using the layers directly or within a stack or brick, but still got the same problem.

I have habilitated the maximum ram use in R (`memory.limit(size = 65535) [1] 65535`).

I have tried with a simple loop to see if the memory hit the maximum and I can see the machine is using the maximum memory assigned.

Any suggestions of why the machine is not using the maximum available memory?
Ash,